# Feature selection in xgboost vs GBM in H2O

Tags: feature-selection, boosting, importance, h2o

I am working on a big data set( more than 100 variables) and 30 million observations. I tried to build 100 models with a grid search using both XGBoost and GBM in H2O (Sparkling Water).

I realized that the variable selection is completely different in each model when I use GBM, however in XGBoost my top 10 variables are always the same! (And those are variables that makes the most sense for my specific case)

I was wondering why is this happening? Can I conclude that my xgboost models are more robust?

Comment: It is quite hard to provide an answer to this question without additional details. For example how is the grid search implemented? Also why would we care about the variable importance within fold and how is it measured to begin with? Finally, with 30M observations I would expect you should be able to have "some" hold-out data. If not, then the folds should be exactly the same anyway so the error metrics between the two procedures are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The gird search is random in H2O, I have different values for different parameters and each model picks a combination and is trained on the training set. we don't care about variable selection in each fold, but in each model. for example a stopping rule is defined in the search criteria to stop building model after 100 models are built. among these 100 models, each time a different subset of variables are selected as "important variables" but in xgboost, in all 100 models, the five most important variables are always fixed.

Comment: Indeed that is a bit unusual. How are the relative performance metrics in the models chosen? One thing that might be happening is that the H2O models are under-fitted so they give spurious insights while the XGBoost have been able to converge to a "good optimum". Note also that this is a very subtle but real concern in "standard statistical models" like linear regression. Prior to actually reaching the MLE (Maximum Likel. Estimate) of the model parameters inference/testing on their parameters can be misleading.

Comment: @EmmaNej would it be possible for you to post a reproducible code snippet of your steps on a public dataset? (if you decide to post code you might want to consider posting to stackoverflow). thanks!